# Is there a way to automatically install a specific version of a Nuget Package at build time?

Tags: c#, tfs, msbuild, nuget

I have some 3rd party DLL's i need migrating into a TFS Nuget Feed, and I haven't been able to find many articles on the internet about installing specific versions of a given Nuget Package at runtime, could anybody link me to some relevant material and/or provide some pointers to this effect?

Ideally this would be done as an MSBuild Target I think?

Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> To promote a cleaner development environment and to reduce repository
>   size, NuGet Package Restore installs all referenced packages before a
>   project is built. This widely-used feature ensures that all
>   dependencies are available in a project without requiring those
>   packages to be stored in source control (see Packages and Source
>   Control on how to configure your repository to exclude package
>   binaries).

This should help [**NuGet Package Restore**](https://docs.nuget.org/ndocs/consume-packages/package-restore)

One of the topics

> MSBuild-integrated restore in Visual Studio, for NuGet 2.6 and
>   earlier.